# javascript Difference in 2 Timestamps

Tags: javascript, timestamp, duration, difference

I need to be able to get the difference between two timestamps in minutes. I will need to take the difference and multiple it by a rate per hour. I have converted the difference to ms and got the difference, but it shows -1:56:

```
    var timeIn  = time_in; //2015-02-15 15:53:52
    var TimeOut = time_out; //2015-02-15 15:55:56

    var ms = moment(timeIn,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(TimeOut,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
    var d = moment.duration(ms);
    var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");

// outputs: Time In: 2015-02-15 15:53:52 Time Out: 2015-02-15 15:55:56 Total: -1:57:56 <--
//desired output: Time In: 2015-02-15 15:53:52 Time Out: 2015-02-15 15:55:56 Total: 1:57:56 (no - 0:01:56 or if it has hours 1:01:56)
```

I need to output the time difference to the user as 0 hours 1 minute 57 seconds, then calculate the rate per hour. So if the rate was $4.00 and the timestamp difference was 92 minutes it would return the amount to charge, $6.13.

Note: This could be longer then 24 hours. Rate/timestamp is pulled from a database, so is different based on location.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a negative value do this

```
...
var ms = moment(timeIn,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(TimeOut,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
if (ms < 0) ms = -ms;
...
```

Comment: Although it kinda works, it is not getting the desired results.

Comment: What results did you get with the modification?

Comment: I figured out that I had my timeIn and TimeOut reversed. I corrected that. Still would like to figure the other parts out.